# Influencing Web Browser Resource Load Sequence

Tags: html, css, browser, image

I have a legacy site that has dozens of little images on it.  In addition, a CSS sprite is used for a variety of styling components.  My browsers are loading the CSS image after the slew of HTML images, so the styling is blocked by the number of pending HTTP requests.  I really want the CSS to load first, as many of these HTML images area actually not displayed on page load.

Is there an effective way to cause a browser to load CSS background images before HTML images, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Is your CSS file loaded first? e.g. in your HEAD element? if so, it should queue those images before the other images in your pages.

Comment: Yes, the CSS is loaded in the head, so I thought it would load these first, but it doesn't comply.  I've noticed that it is definitely non-deterministic, as different images will require different load times on different occasions.